# Can anyone please use of charAt here in this java code and why 'A' is used

Tags: java

Given a column title as appear in an Excel sheet, return its corresponding column number.Can anyone please explain what this statement is doing

```
result = result * 26 + (s.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1)
```

The code is shared below

```
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); result = result * 26 + (s.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1), i++);
return result;
```

Comment: Do you know what `charAt` does? Let's assume it returns `'B'`, what do you think is the result of `'B' - 'A'`? Please try it in a small program. Can you imagine what this result means?

Comment: I know what charAt does in general. It returns the character at the provided index. So in this code it is retruning the character at the specific index which is specfied by ' i '. But I am not sure about the 'B' - 'A' part.

Comment: Then please try it in a small program. Just do `System.out.println('B' - 'A');` there. Or `System.out.println('C' - 'A');` and `System.out.println('D' - 'A');`. Then think about the result you get, what it could mean and if you see similarities between these three tests.

Comment: It is converting the values of char to int I guess, as it is returning the values 1, 2 & 3 respectively. So in this code  " (s.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1)" will return the difference between the position and it will remove what the initial value of 'A'  is and we are adding 1 over here so that it starts from 'A'. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be correct. The construct `s.charAt(i) - 'A'` is used to "convert" an uppercase (#) letter into its position in the alphabet and the +1 is used to have this starting with index 1 (because `'A' - 'A'` is 0). (#) This only works correctly with uppercase letters, because we're using `A`. Use `... - 'a'` for lowercase letters.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom!! What about " result * 26 ". Why is it used over here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is encoding a string comprised of capital letters into an integer.

Let us say I represent binary numbers using the following representation `(1,0,1)2` to represent the number 5 in binary. If I want to represent 10 in hexadecimal it would be `(10)16` instead of `A`. The number 18 in hexadecimal would be `(1,2)16` and so on.

What the code is doing is encoding character by character on a string and replacing each letter by a number in base 26. The letter "A" is represented by 1, "B" by 2 and so on until "Z" is 26. Therefore the string "ABC" would be represented as `(1,2,3)26`, which is equals to 1 * 26 ^ 2 + 2 * 26 + 3 = 731.

So far so good, but there is a catch. The number of possible digits on each of the positions is 26 but the letters are replaced by 1 until 26 instead of 0 until 25, which would use all the available numbers. The result is that the letter Z cannot be represented within its corresponding digit and goes to the immediately higher digit as "carry one".

Let me explain with an example. The string "AY" is represented as `(1, 25)26`. But "AZ" would be `(1,26)26`, which is actually `(2,0)26`.

But a zero does not necessarily means Z. The string "AYZ" is represented as `(1,25,26)26` which is actually `(1,26,0)26` which is actually `(2,0,0)26`.

Answer (score 0):

String title = "My title";

```
System.out.println(title.charAt(3)); //Prints 't'
System.out.println(title.charAt(4)); //Prints 'i'
```

The reason why 'A' is used is It's changed to decimal value which you can see on the ascii table(http://www.asciitable.com/). Here you can see 'A' = 65.

If you want to know why result is used you should understand what the for loop does:
Here is how for functions;

```
   for(part1; part2; part3)  //Head
  {
     //Body
  }
```

In the head we got 3 parts where:

par1 is executed only 1 time when the for starts.

part2 is a condition which is executed before every loop starts.

part3 is executed after every loop and it's usually a counter or something  which will make the loop to stop eventually

So finally we got an example:

```
String hello = "Hello world";
for(int i = 0; i < hello.length(); i++){
      System.out.println(hello.charAt(i));
}
```

loop 1: i=0 console: 'H'

loop 2: i=1 console: 'e'

loop 3: i=2 console: 'l'

loop 4: i=3 console: 'l'

loop 5: i=4 console: 'o'

loop 6: i=5 console: ' '

loop 7: i=6 console: 'w'

loop 8: i=7 console: 'o'

loop 9: i=8 console: 'r'

loop 10: i=9 console: 'l'

loop 11: i=10 console: 'd'

In your example you have to find each part of the for loop and do the same as I have done to see how it advances in time.

part1: int i = 0;

part2: i < s.length();

part3: result = result * 26 + (s.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1), i++;

body: EMPTY!

As you can see we got **2 instructions in part 3**, so both of them are executed after each loop, but this is the same as doing;

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
   result = result * 26 + (s.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1);
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Lol after watching your coments on other posts I think my explanation was too basic hahah. I'm sorry man

Answer (score 0):

> But I am not sure about the 'B' - 'A' part.

The Java Language Specification writes:

> The integral types are `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long`, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers, respectively, and char, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units (§3.1).

So what are the UTF-16 code units of uppercase latin characters? These characters are part of the [Basic Latin Unicode Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_Controls_and_Basic_Latin), which conveniently contains them right next to each other in alphabetic order. That is, `'A' + 1 == 'B'`, `'A' + 2 == 'C'`, and `'A' + i - 1` is the i-th uppercase character of the latin alphabet. Conversely, given any uppercase latin character x, we can find its ordinal with `x - 'A' + 1`.

So, if we only had 26 excel columns, `x - 'A' + 1` would find the ordinal of the column labeled x.

The next 26 columns are labeled from "AA" to "AZ", the next by "BA" to "BZ", and so on until "ZA" to "ZZ". Therefore,

```
ordinal(s) == 26 * ordinal(s.charAt(0)) + ordinal(s.charAt(1))
```

Generalizing this to arbitrary label lengths is left as an exercise to the reader :-)

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic operations are only performed on numeric primitives, except `short` and `char`, which are automatically widened to `int` and the arithmetic result is also an `int`.

Subtracting the letter `A` gives you the zero-based index of the letter in the alphabet, ie 0 for `'A'`, 1 for `'B'`, etc